# How can I return Sprite or Stage in JavaScript in Snap?

Tags: snap-lang

I edit Snap! open-source and I want to now:
How can I return Sprite or Stage in JavaScrpt in Snap!

```
//I tried:

    SpriteMorph.prototype.sprite = function(spr) {
        stage = this.parentThatIsA(StageMorph);
        return stage.children.spr;
    };

SpriteMorph.prototype.sprite = function(spr) {
                return spr;
};

SpriteMorph.prototype.sprite = function(spr) {
            return this.spr;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you'd do it in a JS block in Snap*!* itself:

[image: returning a Sprite from Snap! in JS]

From the source code, the same applies:

```
SpriteMorph.prototype.sprite = function(spr) {
   return this;
};
```

However, it doesn't make any sense to do that. You already *have* the sprite if you're calling this function! :)